# How do I, RegEx Replace in msword C# :( 

Tags: c#, regex, ms-word

```
<name> Test 11 Test 22 </name>
```

Replaced >

```
<name> aaaaaaaaa </name>
```

Hi,
How can I determine the contents of a range in WinWord.

How can I make for C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Word Automation to open the word document, read the text into your C# application and change it as needed, and then write it back to the word document and save it.

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384) sample shows how to create and write to a word document from C# which would probably be enough to get you started at least.

Be aware that you will have to have Word installed on the machine where it runs and that it's not recommended to run these kinds of solutions on servers.

Edit: Look at this page: [Word Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78whx7s6%28VS.80%29.aspx) for information about and samples for common tasks (including working with ranges) when automating Word from .Net.